# How to disable TX path of ethernet PHY in embedded linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, network-interface, ethernet, yocto, device-tree

In a yocto-based embedded device I use ethernet only to receive UDP packets. Now I want save energy as the device (as well as the UDP transmitter) is battery powered, and the ethernet PHY (a micrel KSZ9031) needs more than 150 mW for idle transmit only.

The PHY doesn't seem to have any "disable TX" register. By destroying the PCB wire between the TX clock from the controller (an i.MX6) and the PHY, I can achieve the power saving without problems on the receiving side, but I don't understand how to disable the clock in the device tree.

Did someone achieve such energy saving? If yes, how did you do it? If no, what would you try?

Comment: Is the network controller capable of doing such things? This would be the first thing I would check. If you can't disable the clock of the device, you might try to reduce clock speed of the device. All new clock speeds should be a fraction of the former clock speed, by power of 2. For example, clock speed of your device is 44MHz, try to reduce to 22Mhz, 11Mhz and so on...

Comment: PS does your network controller support half-duplex? If so, you may try to just set your controller to half-duplex mode.

Comment: TCP/IP, by standard, requires packet acknowledgement, so, disabling TX will break networking (but probably not UDP).

Comment: @paladin I did set the PHY to half-duplex with `ethtool`, but it didn't result in less power consumption. To be honest, I don't know what I PHY does in half duplex mode, when there is nothing to transmit and the other end is always transmitting or sending an idle signal.

Comment: @waltinator Thank you, I added that in the question: I'm receiving UDP packets indeed.

Comment: @paladin I'll try to find out how to reduce this clock only in the device tree. The i.MX6 PLL jungle is a dangerous place to go for a noob like me. (-;

Comment: If your embedded device won't send link pulses, I think the device at the other end will assume the cable is not connected. If it's a modern energy-efficient switch, it will probably stop sending traffic to the port until it detects link pulses again. So disabling TX at such a low level might not work.

Comment: @telcoM At the other end there is an FPGA including UDP packet generator and TX PHY, constantly sending an idle signal between the UDP packets. No listening, neither on the same pair nor on a second pair for full duplex. A rather autistic communication partner. (-;

Comment: _"I did set the PHY to half-duplex"_, don't only set it, verify that it is really working as half-duplex. Not every networking device supports half-duplex, this might include your switches too. All directly connected devices need to support half-duplex. Your switch must also able to support port independent half-duplex. This usually requires an intelligent/manageable switch with some buffer memory.

Comment: @paladin There is no switch. It's an embedded system. The FPGA implements UDP, IP, MAC und PHY layer and the twisted pair is directly connected to the KSZ9031. Not even an RJ45 or a transformer in between. I verified that it's really half duplex by transmitting data, resulting in collision errors.

Comment: Okay, so just make sure both your devices support half-duplex. Verify it by testing! Using half-duplex usually requires some kind of buffer-memory, so make sure your FPGA has some buffer memory, for buffering network communication. Or make sure your software API is capable of doing so. Also increase timeout settings to like a minute, when applicable.

Comment: @paladin As written, the FPGA does not. It's only a transmitter and it would be week of effort to implement everything needed for half-duplex receiving. I don't see the reason. Don't you think the collision errors that occur when I transmit from the CPU side prove that the PHY is in half duplex mode?

Comment: No, half-duplex, like full-duplex must be supported by all devices of a physical network connection to being able to enabled. Many modern "copper" network devices don't support half-duplex any more. So if you have 2 network interfaces, first is supporting half/full-duplex and second supports just full-duplex, you may be able to configure the first to use half-duplex, but the second is only able to communicate with full-duplex. Both devices will detect they can't communicate with each other, so usually auto negotiations starts and brings the half-duplex device into full-duplex mode.

Comment: PS your FPGA is not just a transmitter, it's a full network device, because you said it supports _"UDP, IP, MAC und PHY layer"_. A transmitter is in my opinion just an active/passive electrical connection, like it's used by a repeater.

Comment: Sorry for using the wrong term. A pure *sender* is the better word perhaps. It's a deaf man speaking to a dumb man, so in the end it's not *duplex* at all. But Ethernet doesn't define one-way-roads. But I did set the interface to half duplex and I proved that it worked by seing a collision (which could not happen in full duplex).